# Order of a distribution and its derivatives

Tags: distribution-theory

For $\varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$
 , define $u(\varphi):=\int\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x,0,0)dx$
  for some multiindex $\alpha$
 .

It's pretty clear to me that $u$
  is a distribution.

But can anyone please help show what the order of $u$
  is? It's obviously $\leq\alpha$
  by

$\left|\int\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x,0,0)dx\right|\leq\int_{\mbox{supp}(\varphi)}dx\mbox{sup}\left|\partial^{\alpha}\varphi(x,y,z)\right|,$

but could the inequality be strict? Or how I can one prove that it's not, which I suspect.

Finally, what about the order of the derivatives, e.g

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}u(\varphi):=\int\partial^{\alpha}(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\varphi)(x,0,0)dx.$

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the multiindex $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ not all components are equally important. Since you integrate over the first variable, having $\alpha_1 >0$ makes the distribution identically zero: the integral over $x$ of $x$-partial derivative simplifies by the fundamental theorem of calculus, and turns out to be $0$ because $\varphi$ is compactly supported.

If $\alpha_1=0$, then the order of distribution is $|\alpha|= \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 $. To prove the lower bound, fix a test function $\varphi$ for which $u(\varphi)\ne 0$. (You'll need to argue that such $\varphi$ exists.) Apply scaling $\varphi_t(x,y,z) =t^{\alpha}\varphi(x,ty,tz) $ where $t$ is large. Observe that $u(\varphi_t)=u(\varphi)$. Yet, the derivatives of $\varphi_t$ of orders below $|\alpha|$ tend to zero as $t\to\infty$. So, these derivatives cannot control $u(\varphi_t)$.

Comment: Many thanks! Should it not be $t^{-\alpha}$? Also, would you agree that, assuming $\alpha_{1}=0$, the order of the $\beta-$partials is 0 if they include taking the derivative with respect to $x_{1}$ and $\left|\alpha\right|+\left|\beta\right|$ if not.